# How make an excel cell take a value from another sheet if there's content

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am using Excel to track the order of kit being purchase by a sports club.  I have two sheets within one document, one with the orders and another with the costs of each item.

[image: Item orders]

[image: Item costs]

I would like the cost column to automatically work out the total cost of the items.

I think I need to assign each of the 4 columns a value based on the second sheet (so link them?) and then tell the costs column that if there is a value in those rows add them together.

This is more than likely something that has been covered many a time, but I'm a bit new to excel formulae and if anyone has suggestions they would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that A1 on Sheet1 is Jacket. I am also assuming that the potential values would only be a single size, and that there would not be a case where there were, for example, 2 shirts on one order.

If your format (items, costs) are static, then this should work just fine in F2, then fill the formula down.

```
=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(A2), 0, Sheet2!$B$2), IF(ISBLANK(B2), 0, Sheet2!$B$3), IF(ISBLANK(C2), 0, Sheet2!$B$4), IF(ISBLANK(D2), 0, Sheet2!$B$5))
```

Explanation:
The SUM formula just adds up a bunch of numbers. In our case, each of those numbers is checking if a cell is blank. If the cell is blank it uses 0 as that number. If the cell isn't blank, it looks up the cost on Sheet2. The `$` protects values from being modified when you fill down the sequence.

Limitations:

- If the cost of an item on Sheet 2 ever changes, it'll change all Costs on the Sheet1, not just new orders. If you ever want to get around this, you can "lock in" the values by copying the cells in the Cost column for all current orders, then doing a Paste Values.
- If you insert a new column on Sheet1 anywhere before Shorts, or a new row on Sheet2 anywhere before shorts, it'll break the logic and your Cost totals will be wrong. If you ever need to add a new Cost item, make sure you add it to the end, and add a new `IF(ISBLANK())` to your formula.

Alternate view of same formula for clarity:

```
=SUM(
IF(ISBLANK(A2), 0, Sheet2!$B$2),
IF(ISBLANK(B2), 0, Sheet2!$B$3),
IF(ISBLANK(C2), 0, Sheet2!$B$4),
IF(ISBLANK(D2), 0, Sheet2!$B$5))
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion and exactly what I am looking for, however I get an error because if statements need to have 2-3 ifs and this one has 4.  Do you know if there's a workaround that?

Comment: An If statement needs a statement to evaluate (that's the ISBLANK), a value if true (that's the 0), and (optionally) a value if false. I had some of my letters shifted (was checking Polo to Paid instead of Jacket to Shorts). I've edited my answer. Sorry about that. However, that might not explain your error. Make sure you copy the entire line ending with ))

Comment: Thank you for the ammendments.  I have updated the formula in my sheet but it tell me there is a parse error.  Would this also work in Google Sheets?  My code is as follows:

=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(D4), 0, Costs!$B%2), IF(ISBLANK(E4), 0, Costs!$B$3), IF(ISBLANK(F4), 0, Costs!$B$4), IF(ISBLANK(G4), 0, Costs!$B$5))

Comment: I see in your first IF statement you have $B%2 instead of $B$2. That's most likely the problem. I assume Costs is the name of the sheet that has the prices?

Comment: Oh, and to answer your other question, these functions should work in Google Sheets as well.